# Is it possible to generate a permanent link for a search in Trello?

Tags: trello

So one could bookmark or send a link to a specific view on the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out at the moment you can't do that. It's all done client side but I'm pretty sure this will be implemented at one point.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean save a filtered view? As in clicking "Search and Filter Cards" and selecting members and labels, or entering a search? There is currently no way to do that.

You can save the URL from a Trello search results page, though. Example: https://trello.com/search?q=trello%20development. Just copy the URL in the address bar or save the bookmark.

Comment: Yes, I meant the former. For example bookmark a search with tasks assigned to me highlighted.